# Writing same CSV file from multiple JVM / processes

Tags: java, php, filesystems, locking

I'm porting a PHP application to Java.

The legacy PHP application used to use the following code:

```
$fp = fopen($filePath, 'a+');
fwrite($fp, implode(";", $csvData) . "\n");
fclose($fp);
```

I need to write a Java code retrocompatible with this.

It seems the `a` or `a+` option means "append mode" and that it is atomic and no `flock` is needed.

There will be multiple JVM apps, writing the same CSV on a **NFS filesystem** (it seems it may change a lot of things). We can't change this now but it will be soon.

Does someone know which would be the Java equivalent code?

---

**I'm not expecting someone to give an exemple of how to use a FileWriter**: i know how to write in a file.

I'd like a code stample + an explanation of why the code stample is equivalent in term of locks involved, and that it will not create concurrency issues that didn't exist before with the PHP code.

Comment: java equivalent  code to open the file or write to the file?

Comment: @DevZer0 I guess my edit will answer your question

Comment: The only link I can find that seems to explain some interesting some stuff is http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6631352